# How to eject sas hdd win server 2012 proliant dl380 g9

Tags: backup, storage, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, hotswap

We got Proliant DL380 G9, when I try to eject or remove SAS HDD by taking it offline, the Red LED (Do not remove) is still on. I'm not really familiar with Proliant, on other servers I just take the drive offline and I can safely remove it. This one is not. If I take it out while Red Light is on Logical Drive with be corrupted. Below is screenshot of my drives, I wanted to remove Array B and C after it's full for backup purposes.

In addition, I am intending to use the server as file server. So if I am doing it wrong, please do kindly correct me and direct me to which is the right thing to do. The fplan is put 1tb as a file storage and we will be putting another 1tb to backup the files every week and when it's full it will be removed and replaced by another 1tb drive.

[This is the screenshot of HPSSA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZfPl.png)

Comment: Please add relevant details like the number of disks in the server and the RAID level configured on your controller. A photo could also help.

Comment: Added details, I hope it'll help you understand my concern. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZfPl.png), something is terribly wrong with your setup.

You have three disks, each configured as a RAID 0 logical drive. Therefore you have no redundancy and can't remove a disk without losing the data on it.

Why was the server configured this way?

Comment: Looks like he's trying to use them as JBOD?

Comment: 300gb drive will be a shared drive where we can put files in it.

The plan was to use the 1tb disk as backup drive (We will be copying all the files from 300gb drive to 1tb drive every week and remove it after it's full.

If you have a better idea, please I'm all ears. I'm not really familiar with raid.

Comment: That is not a good way to implement backup. It you wish to do that, use a USB disk or something meant to be removable.

Comment: My boss have this crazy idea and immediately bought hot-swap-able drive server because he thinks we can remove the backup drive without shutting down the server which we are currently doing on other server.

Comment: Any suggestions or answer please?

Comment: There is no answer. You're doing it wrong and should be using USB for this.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the light is continuously burning amber, the drive is failed. You can remove the disk  and put a new, identical, drive in. After about a minute the new disk will be blinking green, and the drive will rebuild if its configured as mirrored or RAID5. After 1 hour it will be Green and working again.

Why are you removing the drive? Is the drive not working? If you pull a failed drive and replace it with a new one, the Smart Array will detect the replacement and start rebuilding the volume (you can use HP Array Config Utility to verify that the volume is rebuilding). This must be done while the system is running. Replacing a failed drive while the system is powered off will cause problems.

Comment: I need to test removing it since later on, I will be needing to remove it when it's full for backup purposes. I am aware on how to install new drive, my problem is I can't safely remove the drive without corrupting it, because the Do not remove button is not turning off even if I take it offline. On other hot-swap servers it's immediately off.